# How to use the tangent line to estimate the value of $f(7.5)$?

Tags: calculus

Write the tangent line equation for $f$ at the point where $x=8$. Use the tangent line to estimate the value of $f(7.5)$

The problem gives the graph of $f'$ with a point 8,5 on the graph. it is noted that the function $f$ is defined for all real numbers and satisfies $f(8)=4.$

So far I've tried $y-4=5(x-8)$ and pluged in 7.5 for $x$, and, solving for $y$, got 4.25.

I'm not sure if that is correct, though.

Comment: Ah, now we got the same tangent line but your result is still different ...

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the tangent line should be

$$y=f^{\prime}(8)(x-8)+f(8)=5(x-8)+4\tag{1}$$

Evaluating (1) at $x=7.5$ gives $1.5$.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line of $f$ at the point $(8, 4)$ and has a slope of $5$. Using point-slope form, the equation of the tangent line should be:

$$y-4=5(x-8)$$

Comment: opps thats what i meant! 4 not 2

Comment: Retry plugging in $x=7.5$ into the tangent line. Because $f'(8)>0$, you should get $y<4$

Comment: I forgot a negative sign which was giving me the wrong answer. i go t 1.5 now